# Regular expression AND operator?

Tags: regex, replace, expression

I have 2 string as below:

```
string str = " 2016/07/19 19:47:46]";
string str1 = " Origin (2)]";
```

I want to get the result not start with a space AND not end with a mark ]

```
"2016/07/19 19:47:46";
"Origin (2)";
```

I used pattern string pattern = **@"^[^\S]"** , but AND operator I do not know.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"^[^\S]", "");
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really, no _and_ operator. It's enough to put both specs in the regex.

Comment: You don't need an AND operator for this. You need all the characters after the leading space and before the trailing `]`. That's easy enough to write an RE for. Something like `"^ .*\]$"`, errors and omissions excepted. And you don't need `Replace()`, you need whatever the match API is in whatever language and API you're using.

Comment: I've tried to do, but `"^ .*\]$"` is impossible

Comment: "Is impossible" is not a useful diagnostic.  Your regex looks wrong, though.  You seem to want `^[^\S].*[^]]$`.

Comment: Sorry, because I do not know, but use `Regex.Replace(str, @"^[^\S].*[^]]$", "")` , the result is wrong.

Comment: @MinhKiyo I told you there might be errors, and I expect you to be able to sort them out by yourself. Probably the backslash should be either removed or doubled.

Comment: Thank you! i understood.

Answer (score 1):

Not space at BOL *OR* not mark at EOL:

`(?m)^(?:\S.*|.*[^\]])$`

I guess the *AND* version is:

`(?m)^\S.*[^\]]$`

Another *AND* version which will allow 0 or more characters, is:

`(?m)^(?!\s).*(?<!\])$`

Answer (score 1):

Implementations of the AND regex operator exist. The [TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr) language has it (notated as `&`) as well as the negation operator, notated `~`. As you can see, though, it's not applicable to the problem. Rather, we can use it to match strings which do not start with a space **and** which do not end with a `]`:

```
$ txr
This is the TXR Lisp interactive listener of TXR 147.
Use the :quit command or type Ctrl-D on empty line to exit.
1> (defun complete-match (regex string)
     (= (match-regex string regex) (length string)))
complete-match
2> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ "")
t
3> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ "a")
t
4> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ "abc")
t
5> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ " abc")
nil
6> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ "abc]")
nil
7> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ "]")
nil
8> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ " ]")
nil
9> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ " ")
nil
10> (complete-match #/~ .*&~.*\]/ "] ")
t
```

The `complete-match` function we briefly define returns `t` (true) or `nil` (false) if the input string is completely matched by the regular expression. (The automaton denoted by the regex reaches an acceptance state upon processing all the characters of the string.)

The regex is `~ .*&~.*\]`. The `&` operator has low precedence so we can parenthesize it as `(~ .*)&(~.*\])`: it's an AND conjunction of two expressions. The negation operator `~` has lower precedence than catenation, so `~abc` means "matches for anything other than `abc`": it doesn't mean `[^a]bc`. So `~ .*` denotes the set of strings that do not begin with a space, and `~.*\]` denotes the set of strings which do not end with `]`. (That has to be escaped in this regex implementation, since it is a regex syntactic character).

These negated sets include empty strings. The empty string matches `~ .*`, because an empty string doesn't begin with a space.

To solve the problem of trimming an optional leading space or trailing `]`, we can simply perform two consecutive regex replacements: delete a leading space, if any, **and then** delete a trailing ']', if any. The "and" logic translates to successive transformation steps: do this to input A to produce B, then do that to B to produce result C.

Regular expressions aren't required for the task, because you can simply test whether the leading character of the string is a space, and conditionally on that take either the remainder of the string or the whole string. Similarly, treat the tail:

```
1> (defun trim-leading-char (str ch)
      (if (equal [str 0..1] `@ch`)
        [str 1..:]
        str))
trim-leading-char
2> (defun trim-trailing-char (str ch)
      (if (equal [str -1..:] `@ch`)
        [str 0..-1]
        str))
trim-trailing-char
3> (trim-leading-char " abc]" #\space)
"abc]"
4> (trim-trailing-char " abc]" #\])
" abc"
5> (trim-trailing-char (trim-leading-char " abc]" #\space) #\])
"abc"
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, I have learned many things.